# Filling the dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am completely new in MVC and ENtityframework.

I want to fill a dropdownlist I have coded the controller like this:

```
var LevelLst = new List<string>();
var LevelQry = from d in db.Products
where d.CategoryLevel==1
orderby d.CategoryName
select d.CategoryName;
LevelLst.AddRange(LevelQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.Level1 = new SelectList(LevelLst);
```

and this is what I have in View Part;

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Product",FormMethod.Get))
    { %>   
         **Level1**: <%:Html.DropDownList("Level1", "All")%>    
         <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
<%}%>
```

It works fine without any problem but I have 4 levels combobox to fill.  Do I have to repeat the controller code for the 3 other levels or there is another way to fill the dropdownlist?  If yes, please let me know in an uncomplicated way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hit 4 times at your database. You could just add 4 properties at the ViewBag with the same SelectList object, for sample, on your controller:

```
var list = new SelectList(LevelLst);

ViewBag.Level1 = list;
ViewBag.Level2 = list;
ViewBag.Level3 = list;
ViewBag.Level4 = list;
```

And render it at your view:

```
<p>
   <label>Level 1: </label> <%: Html.DropDownList("Level1", "All") %>
</p>

<p>
   <label>Level 2: </label> <%: Html.DropDownList("Level2", "All") %>
</p>

<p>
   <label>Level 3: </label> <%: Html.DropDownList("Level3", "All") %>
</p>

<p>
   <label>Level 4: </label> <%: Html.DropDownList("Level4", "All") %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Try to avoid dynamic stuff like ViewBag / ViewData** to transfer data from controller to view. Always use **strongly typed** views.

So you will create a view model for your view.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
   public int ProductID { set;get;}

   public List<SelectListItem> Level1Items { set;get;}
   public int Level1SelectedItem { set;get;}

   public List<SelectListItem> Level2Items { set;get;}
   public int Level2SelectedItem { set;get;}

   public List<SelectListItem> Level3Items { set;get;}
   public int Level3SelectedItem { set;get;}

   public ProductViewModel()
   {
        Level1Items =new List<SelectListItem>();
        Level2Items =new List<SelectListItem>();
        Level3Items =new List<SelectListItem>();
   }
}
```

And in your GET Action, you will set the collection items to the instance of this viewmodel class and send that  to your view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var prodVM=new ProductViewModel();
  prodVM.Level1Items=GetItemsForCategory(1);
  prodVM.Leve21Items=GetItemsForCategory(2);
  prodVM.Leve31Items=GetItemsForCategory(3);
  return View(prodVM);
}
```

Assuming GetItemsForCategory method accepts the category id and return a list of SelectListItems from the data source

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetItemsForCategory(categoryId)
{
  // to do :return the List of SelectListItem for each categoryID
}
```

Now in your strongly typed View,

```
@model ProductViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  Level 1 : 
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Level1SelectedItem ,
                       new SelectList(Model.Level1Items,"Value", "Text")"Select")
  Level 2 : 
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Level2SelectedItem ,
                       new SelectList(Model.Level2Items,"Value", "Text")"Select")
  Level3 : 
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Level3SelectedItem ,
                       new SelectList(Model.Level3Items,"Value", "Text")"Select")
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your HTTPPOST action, you will get the selected value of the first dropdown in the Level1SelectedItem property (same for other dropdowns also)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  { 
    //check for model.Level1SelectedItem property value
  }
  //to do  : reload the dropdown items 
  return View(model);
}
```